# How can I get a private key from a mnemonic phrase?

Tags: web3js, myetherwallet, private-key

I want to convert a 24 words length seed phrase into a private key using web3.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are two options:

Using ethers.js - the example below uses a mnemonic
[ethers wallet documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet)

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');
let mnemonic = "YOUR MNEMONIC";
let mnemonicWallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
console.log(mnemonicWallet.privateKey);
```

This doesn't seem to be included in web3, but has been added to the list of enhancements for 2.0. There are some options described in [this thread](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1594).

**Update Mar 31, 2022**

As of **ethers@6.2.3**, the api now uses `fromPhrase` instead of `fromMnemonic`:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const mnemonic = "YOUR MNEMONIC";
const mnemonicWallet = ethers.Wallet.fromPhrase(mnemonic);
console.log(mnemonicWallet.privateKey);
```

Comment: Code works but I'm not getting the expected result. FYI I'm using a MyEtherWallet recovery phrase as mnemonic.

Comment: Updated answer and tested. This seems to be working. I created a MyEthersWallet, used this code with the mnemonic from mew. Then I used the logged private key to add the account in metamask and I got the same address. Sorry for the initial answer.

Comment: this is great! was able to convert SafePal mnemonic and old MEW keystore into private keys enabling mirroring of accounts in Metamask and SafePal! needed an extra lib called 'keythereum' and everything worked smooth!

Comment: You need to also look into derivation paths. The resulting private  keys would differ according to the derivation paths configured.

Comment: As of ethers@6.2.3 the api is now `Wallet.fromPhrase(mnemonic)`

Comment: How about with Foundry instead of Ethers? I there a way?

Comment: https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/derive-remember-key @currenthandle