# How to create private key from mnemonic and extra-word using web3

Tags: web3js, myetherwallet, mnemonic

In web3js, I can use below code to get private key and wallet address from mnemonic. But how can I get private key if user has mnemonic and extra-word from MEW

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
let mnemonicWallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain "extra-word from MEW".

Comment: while creating wallet from myetherwallet's mnemonic method for wallet creation, there is option to choose extra word along with 12 or 24 words mnemonic.

Comment: What is that word used for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a private key from a mnemonic phrase?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79317/how-can-i-get-a-private-key-from-a-mnemonic-phrase)

Comment: That's not the same question!

Comment: that is for mnemonic phrase only, I want to get private key when user has both mnemonic phrase and extra word.

Comment: By "extra-word" I believe the OP meant this https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/security-and-privacy/mnemonic-phrase-extra-word/ from MyEtherWallet(MEW). The page does state that support for an extra word is very limited outside the MEW Platform

Answer (score 3):

The "Extra Word" is a [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) passphrase. It looks like you're using Ethers.js, so you can do something like this:

```
const { utils, Wallet } = require('ethers');

const hdNode = HDNode.fromMnemonic(mnemonic, passphrase).derivePath(utils.defaultPath);
const wallet = new Wallet(hdNode);
```

The `fromMnemonic` function does not provide a way to specify a passphrase directly, but this essentially does what `fromMnemonic` does with the extra passphrase.